# How to check if an object is a Vue component in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, instanceof

With `vue 2` I could simply just

```
import Vue from "vue"
```

and then do the following

```
if (!(myComponent instanceof Vue)) return
```

Is there a way to do it in `Vue3`?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a very elegant solution but you can check if it has a `render` function.

```
if (!(myComponent && typeof myComponent.render  === 'function')) return
```

Comment: Please note that while this is a reliable way to check for traditional components, Vue3 simplified the declaration of [Functional Components](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#functional-components) in a way that they are now basically no more than a simple Function. The check above is not able to detect such Components. Unfortunately it looks like there is really no way to detect these, other than attempting to use them as a Component (or calling them with mocked args as: `(props, { slots, emit, attrs })` and see if they return a valid template string).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `h()` ([hyperscript](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#creating-vnodes)) function from Vue and check its type property:

```js
import { h } from 'vue'

function isVueComponent(comp) {
  const vnode = h(comp)

  if (!vnode.type) {
    return false
  }

  // Check if it's just an HTML Element
  if (typeof vnode.type === 'string') {
    return false
  }

  // A component that has render or setup property
  if (vnode.type.setup || vnode.type.render) {
    return true
  }

  // Check if functional component
  // https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#functional-components
  if (vnode.type.emits || vnode.type.props) {
    return true
  }
}
```

The last condition is tricky since a function without the `props` and `emits` properties is counted as a functional component.